# How to turn MySQL datetime into different date format?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I've been looking all over for a solution to this and simply can't find something similar. Please don't hate me if it turns out to be a duplicate question.

So I have this code that gets a datetime named 'postDate' from a MySQL row in which I have a row with a: 'title' - 'content' - 'postDate'

It is being displayed as (example): 2016-08-13 20:21:10

How can I turn the DATETIME format into something like 13-08-2016 20:21:10 without having to rewrite my code? Or is this simply impossible?

This is how I have coded it:

```
        //Query the database for the selected posts

    $table = 'page04posts';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM page04posts";
    $results = $jdb->select($sql);

    //Fetch our results into an associative array

    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results );

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 

    for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
    {
        // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist

        if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

        // echo out the contents of each row into a div
        // display data in div

        echo "<div class='container1' style='margin-bottom:2%;'>";
        echo '<div class="h1"><h1>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'title') . '</h1></div>';
        echo '<p>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'content') . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'postDate') . '</p>'; // this gives the date (example): 2016-08-13 20:21:10

        // close div                   

        echo "</div>"; 

    }
```

Thank you VERY MUCH in advance!

Comment: I'd just use a bit of server side script (e.g. Php, JavaScript) to suit the given locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this code out

```
<?php
$dateFormat= '2016-08-13 20:21:10'; //from your example
$date = new DateTime($dateFormat);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'); // 13-08-2016 20:21:10
?>
```

Comment: I get the concept of this, but I don't see any way in which I can use the 'postDate' as the $dateFormat. It gives a 500 error

Comment: Worked completely, thank you very much. What I did was this: 


$dateFormat = mysql_result($result, $i, 'postDate');
$date = new DateTime($dateFormat);
echo '<p>' . $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') . '</p>';